# ActiveRecord query and count by child attributes - better solution?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

**Context:**

- `Categorylist has_many Itemlist`
- `Itemlist` has two boolean attributes--`request_list` & `inventory_list`-- that are either true or false (independently, meaning both can be true or false or whatever)

Now I want to iterate over each of the `Categorylist` where that `Categorylist` contains at least one `Itemlist` with a `inventory_list` attribute set to `true`.

In words: I have a master set of categories and items that I create as admin. Some of these items I want to appear on the request page, others on the inventory page, some on both. On each request/inventory page, I want to display only the categories that have items that I wanted to show on that request/inventory page.

**Solution:**

I have a working solution below, but looking to see if it can be improved on further. Thanks!

```
Categorylist.all.select { |c| c.itemlists.pluck("inventory_list").include? true }.each do |n|
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should work for your requirements:

```
Categorylist.includes(:itemlists).where(itemlists: { inventory_list: true })
```